# Add rewrite rule in plugin: with .htaccess in plugin folder or using WordPress functions

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, htaccess

I need add a rewrite rule in my plugin, and distribute it with my code. All works fine if I put the rule in the .htaccess in the WordPress root folder, but I need distribute the plugin with my rule.

I try to put a .htaccess inside the plugin folder and try to use the [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function but doesn't works either.

Here the .htaccess code that works correctly in WordPress root folder but doesn't works in my plugin folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php$ wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pages/request.php?pid=$1

</IfModule>
```

I try the follow code in my plugin but doesn't works either:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
function add_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'pid';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_init' );
function add_init()
{
    $plugin_url = 'the-path-to-my-plugin-folder';
    add_rewrite_rule('my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php'
                  , $plugin_url . 'pages/request.php?pid=$matches[1]','top');

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rewrite_rules(); // I know this should be called only one time, but I put it here just to keep simple the sample code
}
```

But I always get the error that the URL wasn't found.
What I'm doing wrong? How can I do what I need? I searched for similar questions but none solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: WordPress Rewrite API is not the same as Apache Rewrite module.
>   WP Rewrite API doesn't redirect a request to another URL, it used to
>   parse current URL and fill `query_vars` array.

The issue is in the second parameter of you `add_rewrite_rule` function call. It has to start from `index.php?` and then there should be your arguments, like `pid`, for example:

```
"index.php?pid=$matches[1]...."
```

So your `add_init` function should be like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_add_init' );
function wpse8170_add_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('my-plugin/pages/tp(.*)\.php', 'index.php?pid=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules by visiting `Settings` » `Permalinks` page.

Further reading:

- [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/)
- [The Rewrite API: Post Types & Taxonomies](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/)

Comment: Thanks, so I can't redirect to a script in my plugin directory? like http://<WordPress domain>/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/pages/request.php

Comment: @gsc-leticia Yes, you can't. I have added a not at the beginning of my answer. Also I strongly recommend you to read articles from `Further reading` section.

Comment: Thanks, I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619333/add-rewrite-rule-in-plugin-with-htaccess-in-plugin-folder-or-using-wordpress-f before, for archive purpose (that question has already another answer with some good points) you can reply there too and I will accept you.

Comment: @gsc-leticia done